# Не ставится фон, свойство Background-image не работает

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[Архив с файлами тут](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0A_Z0KSZbh6OGtRRkZmRW5SYk0/view?usp=sharing)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хотел поставить фон в header но Background-image почему то не работает, путь указал правильно пробовал фон в туже папку скинуть, что и CSS с HTML. Но ничего не работает

```
CSS: header{
background:url(images/header-bg.jpg); center center no-repeat; color:#fff; text-align:center; background-size:cover;
```

Не знаю уже что делать

Comment: Не стоит размещать код картинкой, сделайте это текстом и форматированием его в код.

Comment: 100% вы ошиблись в пути к картинке. Найдите ее в инспекторе кода, и посмотрите реальный путь где она должна лежать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы написали параметры вне стиля  `background:url(images/header-bg.jpg); center center no-repeat;`
Поправьте так

```
background:url(images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
color:#fff; 
text-align:center; 
background-size:cover;
```

После просмотра вашего файла сразу видна причина проблем, вы написали стили не закрыв коментирующую линию! у вас написанно в css

```
/* --------------- /áàçîâûå íàñòðîéêè --------

background:url(images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
color:#fff; 
text-align:center; 
background-size:cover;
```

вы не закрыли коментарий  `*/` должно быть так `/* --------------- /áàçîâûå íàñòðîéêè --------*/`
и не написали к какому элементу стили, надо так

```
header{
background:url(images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
color:#fff; 
text-align:center; 
background-size:cover;
}
```

будьте внимательны!

Comment: Не помогло, попробовал ещё раз проверить правильность пути. Вроде бы не ошибся

Comment: " Вроде бы не ошибся" - вот это пугает ))  если возможно дайте ссылу на сайт для проверки, и каким методом вы проверяете правильность пути для изображения?

Comment: @ArtemKyprianov, без взгляда на реальный код, либо на вашем веб-сервере, либо выложенном в архиве, вы предлагаете сыграть в "угадай мелодию" по двум нотам :)

Comment: На данном ресурсе нет возможности загружать файлы!! вы должны выложить ваш код или в редакторе или же воспользоватся другим онлайн ресурсом где можете вставить html + css + изображения вашего проекта, и дать нам ссылку для проверки.

Comment: Уже добавил архив, простите за глупые вопросы, я ещё учусь). Если архив не подходит могу выложить сам код и файлы к нему

Comment: Куда добавили архив? )) ладно давайте сначала, вы хоть сможете описать какие фалы в каких директориях у вас находятся? где находится css файл по отношению к изображению? css файл у вас в отдельной директории? например в папке CSS

Comment: Вверху гиперссылка) CSS файл находится в одной папке с HTML файлом, в этой же папке есть ещё одна папка images в которой и лежит сам фон

Comment: Добавил в ответе ваше решение ))

Comment: Изначально header там был, проворонил :). А за закрытие комментария не знал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Путь должен быть такой:

```
../images/header-bg.jpg
```

тогда всё заработает. Ведь Ваш CSS файл не в корне лежит а в папке CSS наверняка.
Вы относительно этой папки прписываете путь.